# How to read /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old

Tags: xorg, 15.10, gnome-disk-utility

I am getting Xorg freezes every 10 minutes on 15.10. Whereas I can read the last syslog as the current report is concatenated onto previous sessions, I cannot read ***/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old*** as there is seemingly no application to do this.

Any tips from anyone out there?

Comment: It's a text file. Or, rather, it is supposed to be a text file. If it isn't, in your case, then something else is wrong. In any case there is no such specific application.

Answer (score 2):

`Xorg.0.log.old` is just a log file (text file) with an `.old` suffix (which means that it is an old log).

You should be able to open it with any text editor (as long as the file is not too big). The default Ubuntu text editor `gedit` can open it.

In terminal you can use ... for example ...

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old
```

Comment: it's definitely not text - the "Properties" field shows_italic_ Sicherungsdatei (application/x-trash)  ie. means backup or security copy, double click says "no application found"